# How to do inequality filter in pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

Here's the usual code in pandas

```
df= df[df.ColumnA  > df.ColumnB]
df=df[(df['ColumnA']<=6)&(df['ColumnA']>0)]
```

What I try

```
df= df[df.select(ColumnA  > df.select(ColumnA)]
```

The error message `Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1395.select.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try this? My pyspark is a little rusty, but I think it should work.

```py
df = df.filter(df.ColumnA > df.ColumnB)

df = df.filter((df.ColumnA > 0) & (df.ColumnA <= 6))
```